# Is firebase account needed only for receiving notifications in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, firebase-notifications

I've no idea of FCM and GCM and right now I have to receive notifications sent from server. Is it compulsory for me to add my project to firebase?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: GCM is depreciated and if you dont have any idea about FCM then read this doc - `https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client`

Comment: Yes it is mandatory to create a project in FCM if you want to use FCM. You will have to do some setup at your app side as well which you can do by referring to FCM site.

Comment: @kapsym Only for receiving notifications, will I still have to create account on firebase?

Comment: @IbrahimIqbal yes you need to add your project to firebase ,for receiving notifications

Comment: Thank you so much :). Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase cloud messaging is just a way to send push notifications to your application(there are other alternatives).

As for adding your project, you will just be giving few information like your App name. This will generate you a secret key to use to access the FCM service. There are several tutorials available on the net and its free(they won't bill you extra if it exceeds your usage limit).

Have fun exploring FCM

Leaving you a tutorial link: http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-integrate-firebase-cloud-messaging-for-android